# How to use JAVA filter lambda to group Arraylist elements

Tags: java

I'm trying to group by JAVA array list elements.

I have an array of **JSONObjects** like the following, I want to group by the fields **price** and **side** and then sum the shares with new fileds **buyShares** and **sellShares**

```
    [{"shares":20,"side":"B","orderId":"001","price":"500"}, 
    {"shares":20,"side":"S","orderId":"002","price":"501"}, 
    {"shares":25,"side":"B","orderId":"003","price":"500"}, 
    {"shares":10,"side":"S","orderId":"004","price":"501"}, 
    {"shares":30,"side":"B","orderId":"005","price":"505"}, 
    {"shares":35,"side":"B","orderId":"006","price":"505"}, 
    {"shares":35,"side":"S","orderId":"007","price":"500"}]
```

and I want to group by price and by side to have something like the following :

```
[{"price":"500","buyShares":45, "sellShares":35}, {"sellShares":30,"price":"501"}, {"price":"505","buyShares":65}]
```

I'm using the following java code :

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> aOrdersArray = new ArrayList<>(aOrders.values());
System.out.println(aOrdersArray);
List<JSONObject> test = aOrdersArray.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(jsonObject -> jsonObject.getInt("price")))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .reduce((f1,f2) -> {
            JSONObject h = new JSONObject();
            h.put("price",f1.get("price"));
            System.out.println(f1);
            if (f1.get("side").equals("B") && f2.get("side").equals("B")) {
                h.put("buyShares", f1.getInt("shares") + f2.getInt("shares"));
            }
            else if (f1.get("side").equals("S") && f2.get("side").equals("S")) {
                h.put("sellShares", f1.getInt("shares") + f2.getInt("shares"));
            }
            else if (f1.get("side").equals("S")) {
                h.put("sellShares", f1.get("shares"));
            }
            else if (f1.get("side").equals("B")) {
                h.put("buyShares",f1.get("shares"));
            }
            else if (f2.get("side").equals("S")) {
                h.put("sellShares", f2.get("shares"));
            }
            else if (f2.get("side").equals("B")) {
                h.put("buyShares",f2.get("shares"));
            }
            return h;
        }))
        .map(f -> f.get())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(test);
```

and I get sometimes the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["side"] not found.
```

Comment: Wouldn't this code be much simpler if you used a simple Java class to hold your data instead of JSONObject?

Comment: Yes so true, I'll try to get things well done

Comment: You can use gson and create a Java Class to map json to your Java Class, then you can  do any thing you want. Your code will stay clean in this way. ex. https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is compicated and errorprone because you've started on the wrong foot.

You shouldn't be having a `JSONObject` in the first place. The data you do have in your JSON input is regular, and you want to operate on its contents.

The right way to start is to make a java object that represents such a record, and then turn your JSON input into a proper, idiomatic java version of that. You want:

```
@Value class Record {
  int shares;
  RecordKind kind;
  int orderId;
  int price;

  public PriceGroup toGroup() {
    return new PriceGroup(price,
      kind == BUY ? shares : 0,
      kind == SELL ? shares : 0);
  }
}

@Value class PriceGroup {
  int price;
  int buyShares;
  int sellShares;

  public PriceGroup merge(PriceGroup other) {
    if (other.price != this.price) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return new PriceGroup(price,
      this.buyShares + other.buyShares,
      this.sellShares + other.sellShares);
  }
}
```

NB: Uses [Lombok's `@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value). Assume this thing has a constructor, all fields are final, toString and equals and hashCode are in their right place, etc.

Once you have the above two types, then you can convert your input JSON into a `List<Record>`. Armed with this `List<Record>`, then and only then should you start down the path of mapping, grouping, etc.

That error will then, of course, never occur, and your map/group code will be significantly easier to read. Any typos you make will result in compile time errors. auto complete will work fine, etcetera: All the advantages.

To turn JSON into a given type, use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). If you somehow just don't want to add that dependency (you should, really), then write a `public static Record fromJson(JSONObject)` method in your Record class, and use `.map(Record::fromJson)` to get to a stream of Record objects right away, and never go back to JSONObject.

```
List<Record> orders = ...;
List<PriceGroup> test = orders.stream()
        .distinct()
        .map(Record::toGroup)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PriceGroup::getPrice))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .reduce((f1, f2) -> f1.merge(f2))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your code is now vastly simpler to read, all methods have proper names (it is `getBuyShares()`, not `.getInt("buyShares")`) and are discoverable via e.g. auto-complete, and you can for example individually test your `merge` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) you can create a class :

```
public class Share{
    private int shares;
    private String side;
    private String orderId;
    private String price;
    
    //getters and setters
    public int getShares() {
        return shares;
    }

    public void setShares(int shares) {
        this.shares = shares;
    }

    public String getSide() {
        return side;
    }

    public void setSide(String side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

then you can use this one to map object from json:

```
 String yourJson = "[{\"shares\":20,\"side\":\"B\",\"orderId\":\"001\",\"price\":\"500\"},{\"shares\":35,\"side\":\"S\",\"orderId\":\"007\",\"price\":\"500\"}]";
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Type shareListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Share>>(){}.getType();
 ArrayList<Share> userArray = gson.fromJson(yourJson, shareListType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst everybody is suggesting to use object mapped values to simplify your calculations, it is not a must per se. The reasons I can think of are:

- you need to create a mapping for every reasonable type of JSON node (it can be automated to some extent though) -- this is totally fine if your mappings are widely used in your codebase, but probably (!) not worth doing it for ad-hoc one-time-in-use stuff;
- manipulating a JSON tree directly *guarantees* that bindings (de/serialization) do not affect the *original* JSON tree structure (i.e. in Gson (and most likely in Jackson) it is possible to implement a type adapter that does not guarantee a perfect round-trip for data mappings: in-JSON -> mappings -> out-JSON => in-JSON != out-JSON; the same for mappings to JSON and back);
- some JSON libraries (just like yours?) do not provide the object mapping/binding feature at all.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final Iterable<JSONObject> input = (Iterable<JSONObject>) new JSONTokener(inputReader).nextValue();
final JSONArray actual = StreamSupport.stream(input.spliterator(), false)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(jsonObject -> jsonObject.getString("price")))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collector.of(
                        () -> {
                            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            jsonObject.put("price", entry.getKey());
                            return jsonObject;
                        },
                        (a, e) -> {
                            final String side = e.getString("side");
                            final String key;
                            final BigDecimal shares;
                            switch ( side ) {
                            case "B":
                                key = "buyShares";
                                shares = e.getBigDecimal("shares");
                                break;
                            case "S":
                                key = "sellShares";
                                shares = e.getBigDecimal("shares");
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new AssertionError(side);
                            }
                            if ( !a.has(key) ) {
                                a.put(key, shares);
                            } else {
                                a.put(key, a.getBigDecimal(key).add(shares));
                            }
                        },
                        (a1, a2) -> {
                            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                        },
                        Function.identity()
                ))
        )
        .collect(Collector.of(
                JSONArray::new,
                JSONArray::put,
                (a1, a2) -> {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                },
                Function.identity()
        ));
final JSONArray expected = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(expectedReader).nextValue();
Assertions.assertEquals(expected.toString(), actual.toString()); // why? because neither JSONArray nor JSONObject implement equals/hashCode
```